# How to set a custom font for Arraylist Listactivity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, listactivity, custom-font

So i searched and found out that i need to create a custom array adapter to change the font of a listview activity. My list activity consists of an arraylist. So i did as such

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {

private Typeface tf;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int resource;
private int textViewResourceId;
private ArrayList<String> objects;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<String> favorites, Typeface tf) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, favorites);
    this.tf = tf;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.objects = favorites;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);    
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textViewResourceId);
    text.setTypeface(tf);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

and here is my Listactivity

```
public class Favorites extends ListActivity  {

public static ArrayList<String> favorites = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final String PREFS_NAME ="SAVEDATA";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



     Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "annoyingkettle.ttf");

     setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.ListView01, favorites, cFont));
```

This doesnt work, i dont know why. My listactivity crashes when i try to open it. How can i fix this?

And here is my xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ListView01" >
```

EDIT: Here is the LogCat

```
    '09-18 02:36:16.036: E/Trace(15562): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 02:36:17.486: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 7% free 2655K/2848K, paused 251ms, total 287ms
09-18 02:36:17.539: I/dalvikvm-heap(15562): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.781MB for 1127536-byte allocation
09-18 02:36:17.826: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3754K/3952K, paused 274ms, total 274ms
09-18 02:36:18.066: D/dalvikvm(15562): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3769K/3952K, paused 5ms+13ms, total 224ms
09-18 02:36:18.316: D/gralloc_goldfish(15562): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-18 02:36:24.436: D/AndroidRuntime(15562): Shutting down VM
09-18 02:36:24.436: W/dalvikvm(15562): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at com.mkaya.ultimatejokescollection.CustomArrayAdapter.getView(CustomArrayAdapter.java:41)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-18 02:36:24.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15562):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 02:36:27.846: I/Process(15562): Sending signal. PID: 15562 SIG: 9
```

'

Comment: please, show what exactly is located in `CustomArrayAdapter` on line `41`

Comment: 'text.setTypeface(tf);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your `TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textViewResourceId);` is not null.

Try to change

`setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.ListView01, favorites, cFont));`

to

`setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, favorites, cFont));`

Comment: i changed the setListAdapter and the activity doesnt crashes anymore but the text became invisible.The list elements are there but the text is invisible. Also for the first part how do i check ifits null?

Comment: @MuratKaya add `text.setText(objects.get(position));` to `getView`. now you don't need to check `if null` but it is done by simple `if(smth==null)`.

Answer (score 0):

This may because your typeface may be null. You have to place your typeface in the fonts folder in assets and access in the activity like Typeface.createFromAssets(getAssets(),"fonts/yourFontname");.