# How to set font type in ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I have items in ListActivity and I want to set a specific font for items. What can I do? I have no XMl layout only Class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, classes));
    
    //Set in the center
    
        //Set the color of Listactivity

    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 154, 154));

}
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862902/how-to-set-a-custom-font-for-arraylist-listactivity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a custom font for Arraylist Listactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862902/how-to-set-a-custom-font-for-arraylist-listactivity)